# Angular CLI page generator routes and lazy-loading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, router

I have interrogations about how CLI is generating pages and mostly route generation. When generating a new page with the ng CLI, the page module/html/spec/scss are created and the routing module is updated.

1) By default the page is added in the lazy-loaded fashion in the app.routing.module:

```
 { path: 'test', loadChildren: './test/test.module#TestPageModule' },
```

And also in the test.module, the route :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TestPage
  }
];
```

Is also added, with an empty path => Why ? I guess I could remove it all it wouldn't change anything would it ?

2) I've read there :[limiting-provider-scope-by-lazy-loading-modules](https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-by-lazy-loading-modules) that the instance of a service is not the same with a lazy-loaded module.
Then if I want a service to be available throughout the app, event though it has the property

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

a module that is lazy-loaded will have a new instance ? Or I didn't get it.

The example is simple, I have a service that fetch a list of user items and the service store that list as a property. When I when to access the details of an item, in a lazy loaded page, the user list is empty from the injected service, so I guess that's a new instance of it...
In exemples of master/detail implementations I've seen services that fetch details when navigating to it but not reusing a list tha has already been built in an other service.

I'd like to know why the CLI uses that way of doing things if it has such a limitation ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Empty path will tell router, the component to be loaded when you hit the url(in your case 'test') of module.
2. In order to create single instance for service across the app, you need to import the service and add it to providers list in root module(like app.module.ts)